# Removing text from response body

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have some lines of code in Python and thanks to requests and a post request I want to retrieve some data from a server, it should return a JSON file, but the problem is that the response contains a string starting with `/*-secure-`, then the structure of the normal JSON file and again at the end of the response, after the JSON I can see again something which doesn't belong to JSON structure: `*/`. 
How can I get rid of this stuff which leads the JSON decoder to generate a traceback? Thank you!

Comment: Use regex - it's fast and you don't have much to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) function.

```
In [1]: x = "/*-secure-{'test': 'yes'}-secure-*/"

In [2]: y = x.strip("/*-secure-")

In [3]: y
Out[3]: "{'test': 'yes'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly and I would personally go with @wpercy's answer, but I've not posted a python answer for a while.

```
>>> x = "/*-secure-{'test': 'yes'}-secure-*/"
>>> x.split("-secure-")[1]
"{'test': 'yes'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do I dare mention this? (Yes, I do.)

```
>>> x = "/*-secure-{'test': 'yes'}-secure-*/"
>>> x[10:-10]
"{'test': 'yes'}"
```